# Why does tomcat can't run application

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have finished my first Spring MVC web application. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>LevonCorp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-demo-mvc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Maven Tomcat plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>

                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <username>aadmin</username>
                    <password>aadmin</password>
                    <path>/spring-demo-mvc/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven WAR plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>

                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven Compiler plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I built it with `mvn tomcat7:deploy`
But when I try to run it on `localhost:8080/spring-demo-mvc/`, Tomcat gives the following report:

```
Type Status Report

Message /spring-demo-mvc/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

This usually means that exploded war of the web application is not in the $CATALINA_HOME/webapps directory. But it is there! Maybe there is a bug in tomcat 9?